# How to get blob containers list that I have access with my storage AAD access token?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

There's a storage account with many containers,
while I only have blob container reader access role on some of them.
How could I get all the containers that I have access.

I don't have a contributor role on the storage account, no access key, and don't know the names of the containers that I have blob container reader access tole.

How could I achieve this though blob API calls with my storage AAD access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You could not list the containers when the Reader role is at the container level. And the container's name is necessary(the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-properties) shows) to get container.

First, you need to have the Reader role in the Storage account.

**Test:**

Add the scope into the App registration, and *Grant admin consent for xxx*.

[image]

Then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get access token.

Follow the doc of [List Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2), use REST API to get containers that you want.

[image]

If the Reader role is in the Container, the error will be like this.
[image]